# Como não pré-carregar página com autopreenchimento

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma página que precisa de um formulário. 
Por motivos estéticos, optei por não colocar legenda e em seu lugar estou usando placeholder. 
Nesse caso não queria que as informações fossem preenchidas automaticamente.
Como faço para inibir esse carregamento automático?

Answer (score 1):

talvez o autocomplete off te ajude

```html
  <form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Fonte:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: não funcionou. Por algum motivo não serviu para nenhum campo.

Comment: parece que o **chrome** esta ignorando, esta tag. uma alternativa encontrei em outra question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582380/4591907
ele diz que precisa colocar em todos os campos, e no form tambem... todos "false" ao invez de "off"

Comment: Continua ignorando. Alterei em todas do jeito que me falou.

Answer (score -1):

As melhores soluções para o seu problema são o  [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/#examples) e o [LazyLoad](https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/), ambos funcionam de forma parecida e carregam quando o Browser é rolado para baixo e "passa" pelo componente.

Exemplo jScroll:
HTML:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <a href="example-page2.html">next page</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.scroll').jscroll();
```

Simples assim =]

Comment: Não é bem esse o problema. Essas informações que são preenchidas automaticamente a que me refiro são os pré-carregamentos de campos input que estejam salvas no navegador. Campos como email e senha que já estão salvas no navegador, mas que eu não gostaria que aparecesse imediatamente ao carregar.